# Is there a possibility of a flutter app running on old version with old packages?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

**Problem**:

Because google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.3 depends on intl >=0.16.0 <=0.16.1 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0, google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.3 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
So, because markets depends on both flutter_localizations from sdk and google_map_location_picker 3.3.5, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because markets depends on both flutter_localizations from sdk and google_map_location_picker 3.3.5, version solving failed.)

**What's Tried:** - Even my own solution on 2nd link doesn't work this time :D :(

[Dart Packages: Dependency conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548782/dart-packages-dependency-conflicts)

[How to solve multi dependency version conflicts simply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64984277/how-to-solve-multi-dependency-version-conflicts-simply)

And whenever i try changing packages version as shown by help messages on Android Studio, even if i change that to specific version then other packages gets in the conflict and goes on nd on...

**Major solutions for these scenarios:**

"any" doesn't working on this case even after replacing every package to "any"

"dependency override also doesn't solving the problem"

**Flutter Doctor:**

```
flutter doctor -v
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Warning
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project. You may also pass the --ignore-deprecation flag to
ignore this check and continue with the deprecated v1 embedding. However,
the v1 Android embedding will be removed in future versions of Flutter.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
The detected reason was:

  C:\Users\Anas\Desktop\Upwork client projects\sez-customer-app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1526], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.2 at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 097d3313d8 (9 days ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
    • Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Anas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Anas\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1526]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.56

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Duplicate of [flutter downgrade error - There is no previously recorded version for channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545480/flutter-downgrade-error-there-is-no-previously-recorded-version-for-channel)

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you don't want to upgrade your flutter project or know that it will bring some packages to conflict. you can work with your old embedding v1 flutter or any version that's old by just downgrading flutter version.

Solution:

[flutter downgrade error - There is no previously recorded version for channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545480/flutter-downgrade-error-there-is-no-previously-recorded-version-for-channel)

or if above link ever expired then following is the solution:-

- cd to flutter directory, e.g. /home/elia/snap/flutter/common/flutter
- then do:
- git checkout 1.22.6